# Property 'getAllByRole' does not exist on type 'Screen'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm working on a web application in which the front end is built using ReactJs. When I run the code, I'm getting this error as mentioned.

```
 TypeScript error in My_project/src/unitTestUtils.tsx(79,27):
Property 'getAllByRole' does not exist on type 'Screen'.  TS2339

  > 79 |   const rowGroups = scope.getAllByRole("rowgroup");
```

When I suppress the error with `// @ts-ignore`, everything is working fine. Please tell me how to get resolve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are using `Screen` type form `@testing-library/react`. There is a `Screen` type in `lib.dom.d.ts` and it is resolved by `tsconfig`